# Angular 2: What is the exact difference between private and public attributes in components?

Tags: angular

Could someone explain the difference between private and not private attributes in components in Angular 2? Like with `private_text` and `other_text` in this example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<div>{{private_text}}</div><div>{{other_text}}</div>'
})
export class MyComponent {

  private private_text:string;
  other_text:string;

  constructor() {
    this.private_text = "hello";
    this.other_text = "hello";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`private` and `public` is something that is only utilized by tools that statically analyze TypeScript code.

At runtime private and public are meaningless because JS doesn't know about them.

TypeScript tools also are not checking the template string for binding expressions that might violate TypeScript rules. This is the reason that it doesn't matter for the template whether the property is private or public.

As far as I know it is planned to improve template analyzing functionality to recognize all kind of mistakes. But that's only the future.

Comment: Hello. But should the template access those private properties? Wouldn't it be better to use a mutator? How does this affect Unit Testing / TDD? Basically what is the angular 2 correct way, if any?

Comment: Template binding to private fails in AoT compilation AFAIK (I don't use TS myself).

Comment: thank you for your answer. We use Angular with TS. Lately it's been adopted accessing private properties in the template. It does work. 
But since I come from a OOP background, it confuses me. So I am trying to find out if this is supported/accepted/recommended.

Comment: @Edgar this might help https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17871 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11422#issuecomment-293612933

Comment: That's great. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

**Public:**

Typescript members are public by default.

So if I have a class `myClass` with the method `public myMethod() {}` or just `myMethod(){}` then import my class into another file. I now define in my constructor of another class `constructor(my_class: myClass) {}`. This now lets me call `this.my_class.myMethod()` wherever I want in my other class. If it was private. This would not work.

**Private:**

"When a member is marked private, it cannot be accessed from outside of its containing class"

Really confused why no one has referenced this yet. I think the following link will really help.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers

Comment: Actually, this is an excellent explanation. But, I wanted to ask, are private variables still available to all areas of the class that creates them.

Answer (score 4):

**Answer is for Angular 2 Using Typescript**

A typescript file is always compiled to javascript and since there is no access specifier in javascript so

1. A private variable declared in typescript will be compiled as local variable whereas
2. A public variable will get compiled as global variable(i.e outside the function body in javascript).

If you dont mention access specifier by default it is private so private_text and other_text has no difference

Comment: It might be obvious to some why this answer was down voted but it's always useful to add a comment so everyone can see why and learn from it, including the question answerer...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's public/protected by default. Try inheriting and modifying a parent class variable without a modifier specified - no errors; now try specifying it as private...

Answer (score 4):

private and public are typescript concepts, not Angular2.

Writing in typescript is encouraged because it is a mechanism for enforcing some rules on the JS you're writing, which should be highlighted when you transpile to ES5.

Using private variables in classes is leveraged by the dependency injection in Angular2 as well, to save you having explicitly assign them in the constructor too.

For example -

```
export class LoggingService {

    constructor(private _appConfig: AppConfig) { }

    someMethod() {

      // you can use this._appConfig without having to explicitly define it

    }
}
```