# Make a service variable global in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

How can I make a variable in a service in Angular 2 as a global variable so that two different components can access and modify it?

```
public myMap : Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();
```

This is the map in the service and I'm populating it initially using a component. Now after some time in the application, I need to access the same populated map using a different component. How can I do this?

When I access the map using another component, it displays as undefined.

Comment: Have you shared your service among two components?

Comment: 1. Fetch data in each component in server. 2. Fetch data once, store in local storage, update storage when fetch data again.

Comment: How do I share the service among the components?

Comment: I don't want to fetch data in each component which is why I created a Map so that the database isn't hit twice and data access will be faster.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a shared service among all components. Inside the service, declare a variable that will hold the value you want to share among components. Then use getter and setter to assign, retrieve or modify the variable from service without making a call to the server.

Here's a simple [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/juF6ICGAqPbXkEHkBuFW?p=info) of sharing a variable among multiple components.

`shared.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppService{
    myGlobalVar;

    constructor(){
      this.myGlobalVar = true;
      alert("My intial global variable value is: " + this.myGlobalVar);
    }

    setMyGV(val: boolean){
      this.myGlobalVar = val;
    }

    getMyGV(val: boolean){
      return this.myGlobalVar;
    }
}
```

Add the service in `app.module.ts` Providers:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [ AppService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In `component.ts` inject the service and use it to set, retrieve or modify the variable.

```
constructor(private appService: AppService) { }

  changeGV(val){
    this.appService.setMyGV(val);
  }

  showGV(){
    alert("GV: " + this.appService.getMyGV());
  }
```

Comment: In the above example can I have another component which accesses the variable myGlobalVar?

Comment: Can't really tell why its not working without looking at the code. Make sure, you have added the service in `app.module.ts` `providers`, NOT individually in each component. And for the example above, you can have as many component you want to share the service, its the same way, you inject the service and use the get and set methods. Here's an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/FWoNtfE4ic3Hi6RdCMsc?p=info) where service is shared by six components.

Comment: Okay, I got that. Should the service be injected privately or publicly? Also how does the private or public affect it?

Comment: Usually services are injected as `private`. You can read about `public` vs `private` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39119143/5556177)

Comment: Is the shared service for all connected users or the current only?  I want to make sure it's per user and not for all the users.

Answer (score 9):

Angular service is singleton for all components below the component where you inject your service.

In other word, when you inject your service in Component A, it will take the already existed instance of this service, if not it is not existed it will create
an instance.

So when all the components get the same instance, every property inside it will be shared for of them.

Comment: What do you mean by below the component? The two components I'm using are completely unrelated.

Comment: Sorry i mean when we define the service as provider in the module it will be a singleton for all the components that belong to that module.