# Need help passing variable to dialog in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Trying to pass the URL id from the last page a user was on to a service that I can reference in a dialog.

issuer.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class IssuerService {

private urlidSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
currentUrlid = this.urlidSource.asObservable();
public onChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {
  }

  changeUrlid(urlid: string) {
    this.currentUrlid = of(urlid);
    this.onChange.emit(urlid);
  }


}
```

Page that has the URL id I want (dashboard.component.ts)

```js
import { IssuerService } from './../../issuer.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
urlid: string;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private issuerService: IssuerService,
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) {}

newUrlid() {
  this.issuerService.changeUrlid(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  console.log(this.urlid);
}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Get URL ID
    this.issuerService.onChange.subscribe(urlid => this.urlid = urlid);
    this.newUrlid();
}
```

Component I want to read the value in:

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { IssuerService } from './../../issuer.service';

    urlid: string;

    constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router,
      private issuerService: IssuerService,
      public dialog: MatDialog
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.issuerService.onChange.subscribe(urlid => this.urlid = urlid);
console.log(this.urlid);
console.log(this.urlid);
console.log(this.urlid);

  }
```

All 3 of those console.logs come back as undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the **`console.log`** inside subscribe

```
   this.issuerService.onChange.subscribe(urlid => {
           this.urlid = urlid;
           console.log(this.urlid);
   });
```

Comment: That did it, thank you! Will accept when time allows.

Comment: Is there a way to access this value when it hasn't been changed? My goal is that when a user goes to a page with a URL ID it will get stored in my service. Then if they navigate to a page without a URL ID I will still know which ID they visited last.

Is this possible?

Comment: you can store in service variable or localstorage, mark if this helped

Comment: Mind linking on how to store in service variable or localstorage? I am not familiar with either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480311/make-a-service-variable-global-in-angular-2

Comment: I was not able to get this working -- should I open a new question or do you mind helping here?

Comment: posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658155/need-help-accessing-variable-from-service-in-angular-2

I cannot get the value to display on a different page outside of dashboard.