# Need help accessing variable from Service in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Passing the URL id from the last page a user was on to a service that I can reference in a dialog.

issuer.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class IssuerService {


private urlidSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
currentUrlid = this.urlidSource.asObservable();
public onChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor () {
  }

  changeUrlid(urlid: string) {
    this.currentUrlid = of(urlid);
    this.onChange.emit(urlid);
  }

  getUrlid(currentUrlid: string) {
    return this.currentUrlid;
  }


}
```

Page that has the URL id I want (dashboard.component.ts)

```js
import { IssuerService } from './../../issuer.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
urlid: string;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private issuerService: IssuerService,
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) {}

newUrlid() {
  this.issuerService.changeUrlid(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  console.log(this.urlid);
}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Get URL ID
    this.issuerService.onChange.subscribe(urlid => this.urlid = urlid);
    this.newUrlid();
}
```

Component I want to read the value in:

```js
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { IssuerService } from './../../issuer.service';

        urlid: string;

        constructor(
          private route: ActivatedRoute,
          private router: Router,
          private issuerService: IssuerService,
          public dialog: MatDialog
        ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
 this.issuerService.onChange.subscribe(urlid => {
           this.urlid = urlid;
           console.log(this.urlid);
   });

  }
```

So currently when I visit my dashboard page it will display the value of 2 which is correct. My goal is that when a user visits any page I can read this value of 2. How can I access this value? The above code works and my Header displays 2 but only when on the dashboard page. I need it to display 2 no matter what page the user is on.

Comment: why you are passing  getUrlid() id here? you can just use the same method

Comment: If I were to access this Service from a different component (home.component.ts) how would I display "2" (the value contained in urlid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqxw3k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fissuer%2Fissuer.service.ts), and It's modified list:

- use queryPamas to get query string, not params (DashboardComponent)
- use ReplaySubject(1) to return the last urlId; it's don't have a default value, just return prev one value (IssuerService)
- get observable from getUrlid and subscribe it in components that want to show url id

[image]

```js
export class IssuerService {


  private urlidSource = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

  constructor() {
  }

  changeUrlid(urlid: string) {
    this.urlidSource.next(urlid);
  }

  getUrlid() {
    return this.urlidSource;
  }

}

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  urlid: string;
  constructor(
    // private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private issuerService: IssuerService,
    // public dialog: MatDialog
  ) { }

  newUrlid() {
    // Get URL ID
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((queryParam) => {
      const id = queryParam['id'];
      if (!id) {
        return;
      }
      this.issuerService.changeUrlid(id);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newUrlid();

    this.issuerService.getUrlid().subscribe(urlid => {
      this.urlid = urlid;
    });
  }

}

export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  urlid;
  constructor(
    private issuerService: IssuerService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.issuerService.getUrlid().subscribe(urlid => {
      this.urlid = urlid;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a parameter for your get Method since you already have the value inside the service,

```
  getUrlid() {
    return this.currentUrlid;
  }
```

and you can use retrieve the value in the 2nd component as follows,

```
this.issuerService.currentUrlid.subscribe((value: string) => {
         this.urlid = value;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and then put console.log(this.issuerService.getUrlid()); in my code. It doesn't return a value, it returns an Observable "Observable {_isScalar: false, source: BehaviorSubject}"

Comment: oh forgot the fact that it was observable , check the updated one

Comment: Sorry I am useless --- I am very new still. I am getting the following error: 

[ts] Property 'asObservable' does not exist on type 'Observable<string>'.

Comment: @user68288 did you try with `this.issuerService.getUrlid().subscribe(urlid => {
           this.urlid = urlid;
           console.log(this.urlid);
   });`

Comment: `asObservable` is Subject's type not Observable, I think you can try `this.issuerService.currentUrlid.subscribe(...)` or `this.issuerService.onChange.asObservable().subscribe(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the help but still not quite there.

I used this code:  `  this.issuerService.currentUrlid.subscribe((value: string) => {this.urlid = value;});
console.log(this.urlid);`

The console.log shows an blank in my console. Any idea why?

Comment: I am guessing it has to do with my service starting with: private urlidSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

Comment: @ChunbinLi -- do you mind taking a look? Can't get these to not be blank.

Comment: is same result from `this.issuerService.onChange.asObservable().subscribe(...)` ?

Comment: maybe you can use Subject not BehaviorSubject because I can't see default value  to use

Comment: Doing the asObservable returns: undefined. Here is code I used:

   this.issuerService.onChange.asObservable().subscribe((value: string) => {this.urlid = value; });
console.log(this.urlid);
console.log(this.urlid);



When I switched to subject it just returns everything as undefined -- I can't even get the blank any more.