# Having multiple themes with custom colors for Angular Material and custom components

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I'd like to have a few themes in my app, but along with Angular Material themes I also want to define custom colors that are used by specific components and elements that aren't part of Angular Material. Whenever I change a theme those custom colors should be changed as well. 
Let's say I have a file that defines colors for each theme, then I'd like to import it in an arbitrary scss file and utilize the colors to style some elements

```
@import "custom-colors"

.my-elem {
 color: $textColor;
}
```

Then, if I need to change a theme I would apply a specific class to the outer most container of the app, and after this I'd like `$textColor` to have another value, so that `color` of the `.my-elem` would change.

Is there any way of doing this without writing something like

```
.another-theme {
 .my-elem {
   color: $textColorOfAnotherTheme;
 }
}
```

In every component that should be affected by theme changing?

Answer (score 1):

> There are **2 ways** to change themes
>   1. Adding **parent class** to your root component
>   2. Changing **file name** (As [angular material](https://material.angular.io/) done)

**1. You can add css with parent class (Example below)**

```
.light {
 mat-form-field {
  color: white;
 }
 my-custom-element {
 color: white;
 }
}
.dark {
 mat-form-field {
  color: black;
 }
 my-custom-element {
  color: black;
 }
}
```

and when user change theme, you can change class on your root element `<app-component class="light">`

There are various ways to do it: [Having global varible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483875/11719787), [Using Event Emitter](https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

**2. Changing file names, same file without parent class will be divided into `light.css` and `dark.css`**

and upon user changing theme, you can replace `<link ref="stylesheet" href="light.css">`

Angular way of doing this is, using [Rendere 2 Set Attribute](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

Comment: I see, I have already chosen the first option, thanks for the answer